# ES / JVM Memory Locking in Unpriv. Linux Container (LXD/LXC)

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, ubuntu-16.04, lxc, lxd

I've seen a good bit about docker setups and the like using unpriv containers running ES. Basically, I wan't to set up a simple "prod cluster". Have a total of two nodes, one physical (for data), and one for Injest/Master (LXD Container).

The issue that I've run into is using `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` as a config option to lock memory (avoid swapping) on my *container* master/injest node.

```
[2018-02-07T23:28:51,623][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2018-02-07T23:28:51,624][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2018-02-07T23:28:51,625][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 65536, hard limit: 65536
[2018-02-07T23:28:51,625][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example: 
    # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
    elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
    elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
...
[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked
```

Now, this makes sense given that the ES user can't adjust ulimits on the host. Given that I know enough about this to be dangerous, is there a way/how do I ensure that my unpriv container, can lock the memory it needs, given that there is no ES user on the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just call this resolved - set swapoff on parent, and leave that setting to default in container. Not what I would call "the right way" as asked in my question, but good/close enough.